# Closed form for solution of $\ln(x)\ln(x+1)=1 $

Tags: logarithms, closed-form, lambert-w

Is it possible to find a close form for the solution of this equation (maybe with the use of Lambert W function)?

$$ \ln(x)\ln(x+1)=1 $$

Comment: Maple and Wolfram Alpha find no closed-form solution.  I see no reason to expect it has anything to do with LambertW.

Comment: Yeah, Lambert lets you solve thinks like $y\ln y=1,$ but I don't see a way to get this in that form.

Comment: If $\log x = 1/\log(1 + x)$ then $x = \exp(1/\log(1+x))$. It turns out the iteration $x \leftarrow \exp(1/\log(1+x))$ settles on 2.307222479767134...

Comment: It is possible that this [Lagrange reversion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e-1%2Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5B%281%2Bx-x%5E%28ln%28x%2B1%29%29%29%5En%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C6%7D%5D%2Cx%3De-1.0) is a solution, but the convergence is slow. Otherwise, you can try another strategy.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you! I tried to sum more terms of the Lagrange reversion, expecting that I would get close and closer to the right value, but that was not the case. Do you know why? Just to understand better, here is the general form https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem, why you set f(x)=1+x-x^(ln(x+1)), y=1?

Comment: @user967210 Usually the series is fairly quick, but instead of the article’s $v=x+y f(v)$, try $x=a+b f(x)$. In the WA link, $f(x)=1+x-x^{\ln(x+1)},b=1,a=e-1\implies x=(e-1)+1(x+1+x-x^{\ln(x+1)})$. If $f(x)$ were $a=e,f(x)=x-x^{\ln(x+1)}$, it would diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A separate solution using Lambert function.*

If we expand
$$f(x)=\log(x)\log(x+1)-1$$ as series around $x=0$ and just use the first term, the solution is
$$x=\frac{1}{W(1)}=\frac{1}{\Omega}=\omega$$ Expanding again around $x=\omega$
$$f(x)=-(1-\log (\omega ) \log (1+\omega ))+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,a_n \,(x-\omega)^n$$

Defining
$$a_n=\frac{\log (\omega +1)}{n \,\omega ^n}+\frac{\log (\omega )}{n\,(\omega   +1)^n}-\frac {b_n}{n!\,\omega ^{n-1} \,(\omega   +1)^{n-1}}$$

the first coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & b_n \\
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 6 \omega +3 \\
 4 & 22 \omega ^2+22 \omega +8 \\
 5 & 100 \omega ^3+150 \omega ^2+110 \omega +30 \\
 6 & 548 \omega ^4+1096 \omega ^3+1214 \omega ^2+666 \omega +144 \\
 7 & 3528 \omega ^5+8820 \omega ^4+13104 \omega ^3+10836 \omega ^2+4704 \omega +840 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Truncating to any order, we can use power series reversion and have the exact coefficients. Trying, the numerical values are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & x_{(k)} \\ 
 1 & 2.3050703\\
 2 & 2.3033257 \\
 3 & 2.3083386 \\
 4 & 2.3068490 \\
 5 & 2.3073554 \\
 6 & 2.3071730 \\
 7 & 2.3072415 \\
 8 & 2.3072150 \\
  9 & 2.3072255 \\
 10 & 2.3072212 \\
 11 & 2.3072230\\
 12 & 2.3072223 \\
 13 & 2.3072226 \\
 14 & 2.3072224 \\
 15 & 2.3072225 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ This is extremely slow for quite few decimal places.

Comment: Wow! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The number
$$x=2.3072224797671340050176675978910511364349575707671\cdots$$
surprizingly close to $\log(10)$
is known in the $ISC$ to be precisely the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log(x)\,\log(x+1)-1$$

What is interesting is, if $x_0=\log(10)$, by Darboux theorem, Newton method should converge to the solution wtithout any overshoot
of the solution since
$$f(x_0)\times f''(x_0) =0.00013878 ~~>~0$$

The convergence is very fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{2.30}25850929940456840179914546843642076011014886288 \\
 1 & \color{red}{2.30722}19378768308564732222822813490367349349200691 \\
 2 & \color{red}{2.3072224797671}265755214115256783516726665701256023 \\
 3 & \color{red}{2.3072224797671340050176675978}896545894505276172324 \\
 4 & \color{red}{2.3072224797671340050176675978910511364349575707671}\\
 \end{array}
\right)$$

We can have **totally explicit formulae** using **one** single iteration of Newton-like
method of order $n$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n &  x_{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 &  \color{red}{2.30722}193787683085647322 & \text{Newton}\\
 3 &  \color{red}{2.30722247}865584766172127 & \text{Halley}\\
 4 &  \color{red}{2.30722247976}941421518848 & \text{Householder}\\
 5 &  \color{red}{2.3072224797671}2983685267  & \text{no name}\\
 6 &  \color{red}{2.3072224797671340}1249354  &\text{no name}\\
 7 &  \color{red}{2.3072224797671340050}0429  &\text{no name}\\
 8 &  \color{red}{2.3072224797671340050176}9  & \text{no name}\\
 9 &  \color{red}{2.30722247976713400501767} &\text{no name}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you are not afraid by long coefficients,build the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant (have look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PadeApproximant%5BLog%5Bx%5DLog%5Bx%2B1%5D%2C%7Bx%2CLog%5B10%5D%2C%7B2%2C2%7D%7D%5D))
$$P_{(2,2)}=\frac {a_0+a_1 t+a_2 t^2  }{1+b_1 t+b_2 t^2 }\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=x-\log(10)$$ and, at the price of a quadratic equation
$$x=\color{red}{2.307222479767134}51$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew some of these approximation methods. If I want to use the Lagrange reversion theorem, would I need much more computation to get the same level of approximation as in Padè approximant? Sorry for the naiveness, what is the ISC?

Comment: @user967210. **I**nverse **S**ymbolic **C**alculator. I tried Lagrange reversion : very slow and a lot of computation. Don't be sorry and don't think about naiveness : there is no stupid question but stupid answers are possible. Cheers :-)